# PHP - RSS - Geolocalisation

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, geolocation, rss

I have an crazy idea here, but I need your help. My car can connect to the internet and read a RSS Feed. I wanted to create a small tool that will generate RSS feed from PHP, that could be read by the car. All of this currently works (The RSS Feed generated from PHP)

What I want to add to my tool is a way to get the car position using geolocalisation. Once I have geolocalisation, I have to do a mysql query and get some results, to generate the RSS items. It's getting complicated, since I have Javascript, mySQL, PHP and RSS all mixed up! And I am not sure what to do from there. In what order should I do that?. Can I maybe get the geolocalisation, send it to another page and generate the rss from another page?

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to refine your question. Are you asking how to know the GPS location of an internet-connected device (in this specific case, your car)?

Comment: You want to get the car position from the car GPS or from the drivers phone for example? Getting the car GPS location might be more tricky...Getting data from internet to your car is much easier than sending your car's data to the internet.

Comment: Sorry for the clarity. Since the car is actually connecting to the internet to get the rss feed, I thought I could geolocalise it just like if the request came from a browser.

So the Idea is that the car connect to a PHP file (http://www.something.com/filename.php), the server would get the geolocalisation, make the query in mysql, generate the RSS and send it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

> *For privacy reasons, the user is asked for permission to report location information.*

---

[W3C](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#security) also states

> A conforming implementation of this specification must provide a
>   mechanism that protects the user's privacy and this mechanism should
>   ensure that no location information is made available through this API
>   without the user's express permission

---

Therefore, unless you have a complete browser or your own App built in your car, you will **not** be able to provide your car geolocation.

The only workaround I can imagine is to use your phone's GPS if you have it with you while you drive.

Comment: Oh :( ok, make sense. Thanks for the information :)